# Formatting python script

Tags: python, compilation, format

***(My first line of python)***
Im currently using the editor thonny on my raspberry pi for a simple python script and I got a compiling error. I think it is caused by the format of the code but I'm not sure. *(I've tried to format it with the VS Code editor and a few online formatters but nothing worked)*

The error occured since I've added the **try-catch block into the while loop**.

```
from gpiozero import Button        
from gpiozero import LED
import board
import os
import shutil
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#init
path = "/home/pi/Desktop/rrr" 
led_green = LED(19)
led_red = LED(26)
btnPIN = 21

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(btnPIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def onOFF():
    led_green.on()
    led_red.off()

def OFFon():
    led_green.off()
    led_red.on()
    
try:
    while True:
         button_state = GPIO.input(btnPIN)
    if button_state == False:
                print('Button Pressed...')
        try:
                 shutil.rmtree(path)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("File not found!")
                OFFon()
            except PermissionError:
                print("Permission denied!")
                OFFon()
            except OSError:
                print("You can not delete that using that function!")
                OFFon()
            else:
                print(path + "was deleted!")
                onOFF()
                time.sleep(5)
         else:
             print("not pressed")
except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

**The error:**
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
File "/home/pi/Desktop/clearHDD.py", line 33
try:
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level*

Comment: `try` and the corresponding `except`s need to be aligned.

Comment: they are aligned aren't they? is there any thonny shortcut to format them properly

Answer (score 0):

Try except blocks are not aligned.
[PythonDocs on how to properly use try except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Try this,
this seems to be the correct indent for your file.

```
try:
    while True:
        button_state = GPIO.input(btnPIN)
        if button_state == False:
            print('Button Pressed...')
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(path)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("File not found!")
                OFFon()
            except PermissionError:
                print("Permission denied!")
                OFFon()
            except OSError:
                print("You can not delete that using that function!")
                OFFon()
            else:
                print(path + "was deleted!")
                onOFF()
                time.sleep(5)
        else:
            print("not pressed")
except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```